# Trying to write an R function: is it the For Loop or the numeric vector that doesn't work?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, vector

I have a function like this (see below) and I genuinely cannot understand why it doesn't work.

The for loop itself, when run separately (not inside of a function) does work perfectly but the function always returns an empty vector, no matter the input value. I was doing the testing on c(3, 0, 4, 0, 99) as code, which should return me c(5, 0, 4, 0, 99). (The ones and twos work fine and have been tested in an earlier task).

```
run_code <- function(code, input) {

  opcode <- which(code %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 99))
  input <- input
  for (i in opcode) {                  
    if (code[i] == 1) {                                                   
      code[code[i+3]+1] <- code[code[i+1]+1] + code[code[i+2]+1]
    } else {
      if (code[i] == 2) {
        code[code[i+3]+1] <- code[code[i+1]+1] * code[code[i+2]+1]
      } else {                                                           
        if (code[i] == 3) {
          code[code[i+1]+1] <- input
        } else {
          if (code[i] == 4) {
            return(code[code[i+1]])
          } else {                                                      
            if (code[i] == 99) {
              break
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(code)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the function `run_code` supposed to do? What is `code` and `input` parameters and what output should they return ?

Comment: In this case, `code` is supposed to be a numeric vector, in which 1, 2, 3, 4 and 99 stands for an instruction that overwrites (changes) the numeric vector itself. The `run_code` function should implement these changes and return the altered numeric vector (`code`). `input` is some input value given by the instruction of the task that kind of tells the function what to do at the beginning (of the loop). Everything actually seems to work on its own, except inside of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following code:

```
run_code <- function(code, input) {
opcode <- which(code %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 99))
for (i in opcode) {                  
    if (code[i] == 1) {                                                   
        code[code[i+3]+1] <- code[code[i+1]+1] + code[code[i+2]+1]
    } else {
        if (code[i] == 2) {
            code[code[i+3]+1] <- code[code[i+1]+1] * code[code[i+2]+1]
        } else {                                                           
            if (code[i] == 3) {
                code[code[i+1]+1] <- input
            } else {
                if (code[i] == 4) {
                    code[i] = code[i+1]
                    return(code)
                } else {                                                      
                    if (code[i] == 99) {
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return(code)
}

a = run_code(code = c(3, 0, 4, 0, 99), input = 1)
```

But what is the main problem? I think the line `return(code[code[i+1]])` is not true. You try to return a value instead of a vector code. I'm not sure that truly change your code for your purpose. But when you try to return a scalar value within the function it does not return the code vector completely.
Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is still what I get:

`> run_code(code = c(3, 0, 4, 0, 99), input = 1)

numeric(0)`

Comment: Yes, the return[...] thing was the problem. Changed it to "print". Thanks!